# Secure writing of data to Firebase via Angular

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I want to setup a public form to write to Firebase via the Angular Firebase plugin AngularFire but it feels like there needs to be some security added so that data is only posted from that form, I can't see any interface to Whitelist a Domain/URL. Is there a way to only accept writes from a specific Form/URL without getting the User to login first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

But it wouldn't help in your scenario anyway: when you're using Angular, all code is running in the user's browser. It might be served from your domain into that browser first, but just as easily the user might have saved the HTML locally and started running it that way.

It sounds like you're trying to secure things so that only *your* code can modify them, probably because you think that your code is the only thing that can be trusted to follow some of your application-specific business rules. Instead of trying to limit access to just your code, I'd instead recommend capturing the business rules server-side. Firebase has a very powerful security and data validation model just for that purpose. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/

Once you enforce these business rules on the server, it doesn't matter how someone access your data. They could be using your code - or somebody could have taken your code (or an API that you've documented) and written a third-party application. Either way: the (security and validation) rules will be enforced by Firebase, so your data will stay valid and secure.